# Error while accessing datastore in Apigee

Tags: persistence, apigee

I'm using the key/value datastore for temporary data storage in my Apigee API proxy.

After working for weeks, it suddenly stopped working, and I'm getting:

```
{
    fault: {
        faultstring: "Error while accessing datastore;Please retry later"
        detail: {
            errorcode: "datastore.ErrorWhileAccessingDataStore"
        }
    }
}
```

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The Apigee key/value map:

- has a limit of 15MB for a single map
- Currently, does not support expiration of data

So, it is very easy to fill up the key/value map if you're expecting the data to expire. Recommend looking into using a `cache`.

Answer (score -1):

This may possibly be a bug or some other problem specific to your environment.  This issue has been reported to our Product Support team for follow up.